# @ng-select 3.x doesn't work mouse click options

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular8, angular-ngselect

After migrating to **@ng-select v3.x** (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select), mouse click no longer works on items. My application uses bootstrap 4 and angular 8. Returning to v2.20.5 version works again normally.

Someone with the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Add a minimal code example to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. Changing the datasource to an array instead of a function (that returned the same array) solved the issue.

Comment: I have been stuck with this for more than an hour. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I had encountered similar issue, sweating to find out why my ngselect was not reacting on click but was selecting entries on tab.
Finally found out why : the items i wanted to use were stored in a `Set` to get it work I made a method in my component to return this set as an array :

```
ngSelectItems() {
    return Array.from(this.mySet.values());
  }
```

with that method everything seemed to work, but no click were triggered on options.
Finally made an coponent array property mirroring my `Set` and use it in the ngselect `item` property to solve the issue.
I thing it's a bug of ngselect.

I created an issue here : https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1405